# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a broken json:

```
Array(1), "40.7197406, 8.563512299999957", "40.7272074, 8.575266499999998", Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0: ["-22.91401497538739,-68.19866465000001"]
1: ["-25.857842171488155,-54.4140132"]
```

I tried `JSON.parse(data[i].coordinates[i])` but I get that error, the json looks like has some strings but i'm not sure how to fix and make it correct

Comment: Where do you get this JSON? Fix the backend instead of fixing broken data on frontend.

Comment: @KoshVery I can't access the site, I am receiving an external json

Comment: Can you share the source link?

Comment: That's not JSON. It's just two numbers separated by comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not JSON, so don't try to use `JSON.parse`. Just split it on the commas and call `parseFloat()`.

```js
var data = [{
  coordinates: ["40.7197406, 8.563512299999957", "40.7272074, 8.575266499999998"]
}];

var coords = data[0].coordinates.map(s => s.split(",").map(n => parseFloat(n.trim())));
console.log(coords);
```